# Is there a way to construct SQL statement to return desired value only if there is a single row found, and return 0 otherwise?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Consider below:

```
    SELECT 
        customer.contact.id
    FROM customer.contact
    WHERE
        customer_office_id = [INTEGER]
```

If only a *single* row is returned, I want the result set to return the `customer.contact.id`, but if 0 or more than 1 rows are returned, I want the SQL statement to return 0 (that is, despite that there are multiple rows, or no rows, I want SQL to return a single row with a value that is 0)

Note - if there is a special SQL case for when only 0 or 1 rows returned are possible, I'd be interested in that as well, i.e if there are no more than 1 rows possible given the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using COUNT and MIN/MAX:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE MIN(contact_id) END
FROM
    contacts
WHERE
    customer_office_id = [int]
GROUP BY
    customer_office_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ec441732770302cae1085007e88fd6e)*

To cover the case when there are no rows returned you can use:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE((SELECT
                  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE MIN(contact_id) END contact_id
              FROM
                  contacts
              WHERE
                  customer_office_id = [INT]
              GROUP BY
                  customer_office_id), 0) contact_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b68542ec3a5dad8c3d8f195c23926c8)*

Comment: Thanks. On my platform though it returns empty set for when no rows are returned, not 0...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set up one example to cover this situation.

Comment: thanks!!  it works!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have success with this as well (assuming I have data with only 1 or 0 rows possible, which after examining my data is the case)

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN MIN(id) IS NULL THEN 0
     ELSE id
   END AS value
FROM   customer.contact
WHERE  customer_office_id = [int];
```

Comment: Check out the last entry [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20dc442920eefd35a92bc48940c17101).

Comment: what if you remove `GROUP BY contact_id`?

Comment: hmm interesting... on my actual shell it returns a set with 0 value, when I remove `GROUP BY` clause.  In the fiddle it throws and error.